# Calculating the canopy size (crown) of a newly planted tree at a future date

Tags: botany, growth, trees

Assuming that one knows the maximum area of the canopy and the age of the tree when it achieves this. And given an initial canopy size from the nursery. How would I calculate the canopy size at a future date.

Whilst certain aspects of the growth are obviously variable... how would I model the growth over the year(s)? I'm looking for a simple formula that I could give to a user in a planning department to develop adaptive lighting solutions for trees in streets.

Comment: Maybe trees branch randomly so there might be no such formula.

Comment: If you can tell the weather years in advance this might be possible. Other than that just interpolate linearly and that'll be close enough maybe?